# How to access multiple #shadow-roots in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

The `<lingenio-view-translation>` element actually extends another element, so I guess this is where the multiple `#shadow-root` tags stem from. The lower one is the `#shadow-root` from the extended element, the upper one from the extending element. How can I access the extended element from within `<lingenio-view-translation>` aka the extending one? `this.shadowRoot` always returns the top one.

[image: multiple #shadow-root tags]

Comment: True. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the "shadowRoots" property. [example](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/master/test/html/shadowroots.html):

```
Polymer('x-zot', {
  ready: function() {
    console.assert(
      this.shadowRoots['x-foo'].querySelector('#foo') === this.$.foo
    );
    console.assert(
      this.shadowRoots['x-bar'].querySelector('#bar') === this.$.bar
    );
    console.assert(
      this.shadowRoots['x-zot'].querySelector('#zot') === this.$.zot
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Alternatives to the above method can be found here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/